# Create a local TOC with arbitrary scope

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I'm using the [kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook/) class, which in turn uses the [`etoc`](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoc/etoc.pdf) package to create local TOCs in my document. Because the local TOCs should be in the margin of the page where where they are called (typically at the beginning of a chapter), they are essentially included like this:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{margintocdepth} % Set the depth of the margintoc
\setcounter{margintocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}

\newlength{\mtocshift} % Length of the vertical offset used for margin tocs
\setlength{\mtocshift}{-52mm}

% Command to print a table of contents in the margin
\newcommand{\margintoc}[1][\mtocshift]{ % The first parameter is the vertical offset; by default it is \mtocshift
    \begingroup
        % Set the style for chapter entries
        \etocsetstyle{chapter}
        {\parindent -10pt \parskip 0pt}
        {\leftskip 0pt}
        {\makebox[.5cm]{}
        \hangindent=0.5cm\etoclink{\etocthename}\nobreak\hbox{\hbox to 1.5ex {\hss\hss}}\hfill\makebox[5mm][l]{\etocpage}\nobreak
        \par}
        {}
        % Set the style for section entries
        \etocsetstyle{section}
        {\parindent 0pt \parskip 0pt}
        {\leftskip 0pt}
        {\makebox[.5cm]{}
        \hangindent=0.5cm\etoclink{\etocthename}\nobreak\hbox{\hbox to 1.5ex {\hss\hss}}\hfill\makebox[5mm][l]{\etocpage}\nobreak
        \par}
        {}
        % Set the global style of the toc
        \etocsettocstyle{\usekomafont{section}\small\raggedright}{}
        \etocsetnexttocdepth{\themargintocdepth}
        % Print the table of contents in the margin
        \marginnote[#1]{
            \parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{Contents\vspace{-0.65\baselineskip}\\\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}\rule{\marginparwidth}{0.5pt}}
            \localtableofcontents
        }
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}
\setchapterpreamble[u]{\margintoc}
\chapter{Introduction}

    \section{Section 1}

    \section{Section 2}

\chapter{Body}

    \section{Section 1}

    \section{Section 2}

\chapter{Conclusion}

    \section{Section 1}

    \section{Section 2}

\part{Second Part}

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Body}

\chapter{Conclusion}



\end{document}
```

This works well, but the local TOC only includes the elements from within the chapter (which I guess is usually exactly what you want). But instead, I would like the local TOC to include everyting from the parts level. Is there any way to do that?

Using `\etocsetnexttocdepth` unfortunately doesn't work and calling `\localtableofcontents` without `\setchapterpreamble` will create a local TOC with the corect scope, but it will be printed on its own page.

Comment: Please help people help you by providing a compilable sample document that people can play with. This should include enough code to reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: @AlanMunn sure, I've added an MWE. I just thought this might be a simple case where that's not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the package documentation section `15. Labeling and reusing elsewhere`

> etoc allows to typeset at some location a local table of contents
> which is defined elsewhere. For this, two simple steps:
>
> 1. insert `\localtableofcontents`at the distant place, and follow it by some `\label{foo}`.
> 2. insert `\tableofcontents\ref{foo}` at the place where you want this distant table of contents to appear.
> 3. in step 1, if you use `\invisiblelocaltableofcontents` in place of `\localtableofcontents`, there will be no typesetting at its place of
>    definition.

You need some way to generate automatically this mark-up with some suitable lables, for example `\label{part:1}`,  but then you will need your chapter to know in which part it is.  Ok I tested with `\the\value{part}` both to generate the label and use as reference for chapters in that part, and it appears to work indeed.

first chapter in first part

[image: margin toc in first chapter of first part]

first chapter in second part

[image: margin toc in first chapter of second part]

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcounter{margintocdepth} % Set the depth of the margintoc
\setcounter{margintocdepth}{\sectiontocdepth}

\newlength{\mtocshift} % Length of the vertical offset used for margin tocs
\setlength{\mtocshift}{-52mm}

% Command to print a table of contents in the margin
\newcommand{\margintoc}[1][\mtocshift]{ % The first parameter is the vertical offset; by default it is \mtocshift
    \begingroup
        % Set the style for chapter entries
        \etocsetstyle{chapter}
        {\parindent -10pt \parskip 0pt}
        {\leftskip 0pt}
        {\makebox[.5cm]{}
        \hangindent=0.5cm\etoclink{\etocthename}\nobreak\hbox{\hbox to 1.5ex {\hss\hss}}\hfill\makebox[5mm][l]{\etocpage}\nobreak
        \par}
        {}
        % Set the style for section entries
        \etocsetstyle{section}
        {\parindent 0pt \parskip 0pt}
        {\leftskip 0pt}
        {\makebox[.5cm]{}
        \hangindent=0.5cm\etoclink{\etocthename}\nobreak\hbox{\hbox to 1.5ex {\hss\hss}}\hfill\makebox[5mm][l]{\etocpage}\nobreak
        \par}
        {}
        % Set the global style of the toc
        \etocsettocstyle{\usekomafont{section}\small\raggedright}{}
        \etocsetnexttocdepth{\themargintocdepth}
        % Print the table of contents in the margin
        \marginnote[#1]{
            \parbox[b]{\marginparwidth}{Contents\vspace{-0.65\baselineskip}\\\vspace{0.1\baselineskip}\rule{\marginparwidth}{0.5pt}}
            \localtableofcontents\ref{part:\the\value{part}}
        }
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{First Part}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{part:\the\value{part}}
\setchapterpreamble[u]{\margintoc}
\chapter{Introduction}

    \section{Section 1}

    \section{Section 2}

\chapter{Body}

    \section{Section 1}

    \section{Section 2}

\chapter{Conclusion}

    \section{Section 1}

    \section{Section 2}

\part{Second Part}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents\label{part:\the\value{part}}

\setchapterpreamble[u]{\margintoc}
\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Body}

\chapter{Conclusion}



\end{document}
```

---

Update: the above is for using `\part`.  It will fail with `\part*`.  Then use rather than `\the\value{part}` something such as `\the\value{mycounter}` having done `\newcounter{mycounter}` and issuing `\stepcounter{mycounter}` or `\refstepcounter{mycounter}` at each `\part*`.  You can also do `\refstepcounter{part}` as you mention in a comment but this appears to be reasonable only if you include only unnumbered parts in the document, else the numbering of the numbered ones will get shifted.  Beware that `\part*` may have another issue of not correctly delimiting the local table of contents according to the [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) documentation, section `21. The \etocsetlocaltop.toc and \etocimmediatesetlocaltop.toc commands`.  I have not tested and your comment (I don't know how to link to it) seemingly indicates you had no issues, but you may have to do things such as that for unnumbered parts, which I found looking for `part*` in the [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) documentation.

```latex
\part*{Extra unnumbered part}
\etocsetlocaltop.toc{part}
\invisiblelocaltableofcontents
```

In retrospect as your comment seemed to indicate all ok, maybe this is not needed and possibly even detrimental.

Comment: Amazing. This works. Thanks a lot! Somehow I didn't find that crucial section in the docs.

Comment: Do you by any chance also know why the in the local TOC, the only the name of the first chapter (Introduction) is propperly indented, while the others (Body and Conclusion) are not?

Comment: I made a [separate post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/680815/182643) for that issue.

Comment: Hi, I just realized that this unfortunately doesn't work if you use `\addpart` (which allows you to add unnumbered parts) instead of just `part`. `part*` also doesn't work. Any idea to fix this? It says `Label "part:0" multiply defined.` Maybe it is possible to set this manually?

Comment: Ah, easy fix. Just do `\refstepcounter{part}` in front of any additional ``\invisiblelocaltableofcontents` calls. Maybe worth adding to the solution.